# PHP dynamic table linked with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

My problem is that I can't get the dialog div and all the other divs inside of it to display the dynamic variables according to the image selected.

I want to be able to dynamically display a table of user pics and when their picture is clicked on the div containing the dynamic table fades to black and a popup containing the users picture and other information shows using JQUERY. Everything works but then popup displaying the respective variables of the user clicked on.

Beginning in the `$memberdisplaylist` inside the td the `$firstname` and `$member_pic` display properly according to the array but when the `$member_pic` is clicked on, the dialog div popup keeps displaying variables from row 1 and does not display the variables in respect to the row of which `$member_pic` is selected. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Also does anyone know the jQuery coding I would need to center my dialog div popup inside my profilepicsdark div containing my dynamic table?

**PHP**

```
$MemberDisplayList = "<table border='0' align='left' cellpadding='7'>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_activated='1'");
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $firstname = $row["first_name"];
    $sex = $row["sex"];
    $age = $row["age"];
    $focus = $row["focus"];
    $lastlog = $row["last_log_date"];
    $firstnameCut = substr($firstname, 0, 10);
    $check_pic = "members/$id/image01.jpg";
    if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
        $member_pic = "<img src=\"members/$id/image01.jpg\" width=\"100px\" border=\"0\" />";
    } else {
        $member_pic = "<img src=\"members/0/image01.jpg\" width=\"100px\" border=\"0\" />";
    }
    if( $counter % 7 == 0)
    $MemberDisplayList .= '<tr>';
    $counter++;
    $MemberDisplayList .= '<td>';
    $MemberDisplayList .= '<a href="" title="' .    $firstname . '"><font size="-2">' . $firstnameCut . '</font></a><br /><div class="memberpreviewpopup" style=" height:100px; overflow:hidden;">' . $member_pic . '</div><div class="boxes"><div id="dialog" class="window"><div id="title">' . $member_pic . '</div><div id="info">' . $firstname . '</div><div id="info">' . $lastlogdate . '</div><div id="info">' . $sex . '</div><div id="info">' . $age . '</div><div id="info">' . $focus . '</div><a href="" class="close"/>Close it</a><a href="profile.php?id=' . $id . '">View Profile</a></div></div></td>';
    if( $counter % 7 == 0) 
        $MemberDisplayList .= '</tr>';

} // close while loop

$MemberDisplayList .= "</table>";
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function codeBinsAddEvent(obj,type,fn){
                if(obj.attachEvent){
                        if(type == "load"){
                            obj.attachEvent('on'+type, fn);
                        }
                        else{
                            obj.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', fn);
                        }
                        /*
                    obj['e'+type+fn]=fn;
                    obj[type+fn]=function(){
                        obj['e'+type+fn](window.event)}
                    ;obj.attachEvent('on'+type,obj[type+fn])*/
                 }
                else obj.addEventListener(type,fn,false)
            };
            function codeBinsAddLoadEvent(fn){
                codeBinsAddEvent(document.addEventListener&&!window.addEventListener?document:window,'load',fn)
            };
            function codeBinsAddReadyEvent(fn){
                codeBinsAddEvent(document,'DOMContentLoaded',fn)
            };

</script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".memberpreviewpopup").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $dialog = $("#dialog");
        var maskHeight = $('.profilepics').height();
        var maskWidth = $('.profilepics').width();
        $('#profilepicsdark').css({
            'width': maskWidth,
            'height': maskHeight
        });
        $('#profilepicsdark').fadeIn(100);
        $('#profilepicsdark').fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
        var winH = $('.profilepics').height();
        var winW = $('.profilepics').width();
        $('#profilepicsdark').css('top', winH / 2 - $dialog.height() / 2);
        $('#profilepicsdark').css('left', winW / 2 - $dialog.width() / 2);
        $dialog.fadeIn(400);

    });

    $('.window .close').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#profilepicsdark').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });
    $('#profilepicsdark').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
#profilepicsdark{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.5;
  display:none;
}
#dialog{
  position: absolute;
  padding:0px;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background-color:#d4e1ff;
  display:none;
  z-index:99999;
}
#dialog #msg{
  margin-left:20px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:14px;
}
#dialog #title{
  margin:0px;
  padding:5px;
  float: left;
}
#dialog #info{
  width: 100px; 
  margin-right:20px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:14px;
  float: right;
  text-align:right;
}
#dialog .close{
  float:right;
  background:#afa1f5;
  bordercolor:1px solid #445cd88;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:13px;

}
#dialog .close:hover{
  background:#af55d9;
  bordercolor:1px solid #445cd88;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The relevant resulting HTML output might be more beneficial than the PhP code.

Comment: in my html on the page that this is being displayed on just has: <div class="profilepics" id="profilepics"><?php  print"$MemberDisplayList"; ?><div id="profilepicsdark"></div></div> The output then generates a line of 7 images per line and when I click on the first image the coding seems to work but then when i click on the second image or any other image besides the first, the popup contains the first image's associated variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an idea of what you're trying to accomplish here. What's happening is that the #dialog div is called without the context of the member you're viewing a preview of.

It's a little messy, but if you make the following adjustments you should be about to call #dialog in context.

HTML:

```
$MemberDisplayList .= '
<a href="" title="'.$firstname.'"><font size="-2">' . $firstnameCut . '</font></a>
<br />
<div class="memberpreviewpopup" member_id="'.$id.'" style=" height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
    '.$member_pic.'
</div>
<div class="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" member_id="'.$id.'" class="window">
        <div id="title">' . $member_pic . '</div>
        <div id="info">' . $firstname . '</div>
        <div id="info">' . $lastlogdate . '</div>
        <div id="info">' . $sex . '</div>
        <div id="info">' . $age . '</div>
        <div id="info">' . $focus . '</div>
        <a href="" class="close"/>Close it</a>
        <a href="profile.php?id=' . $id . '">View Profile</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>';
```

Javascript:

```
$(".memberpreviewpopup").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // This has been updated ==============
    var member_id = $(this).attr('member_id');
    var $dialog = $('#dialog[member_id="'+member_id+'"]');
    // ====================================
    $('#profilepicsdark').css({
        'width': maskWidth,
        'height': maskHeight
    });
    $('#profilepicsdark').fadeIn(100);
    $('#profilepicsdark').fadeTo("fast", 0.8);

    var winH = $('.profilepics').height();
    var winW = $('.profilepics').width();

    // This should fix the alignment issue with the box you mentioned ====
    var profilepicsdark_top = winH / 2 - $dialog.height() / 2;
    var profilepicsdark_left = winW / 2 - $dialog.width() / 2;
    $('#profilepicsdark').css('top', profilepicsdark_top); 
    $('#profilepicsdark').css('left', profilepicsdark_left);
    $dialog.css('top', profilepicsdark_top*2);
    $dialog.css('left', profilepicsdark_left*2);
    // ===================================================================

    $dialog.fadeIn(400);
});
```